# In Toad for Oracle using SQL Query how do I change data output to representative characters

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, toad

I made a query and my output has columA. In column A the potential data is **Dog** or **Cat**,

if the Output is:

- **Dog** then I want it to be shown as **B**
- **Cat** I want it to be shown as **T**.

How can I do this in Toad for Oracle using a SQL Query?

Comment: Can you show us your query ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select decode(columnA,'dog','B','cat','T','not a dog or cat')
from dual
```

Comment: decode accepts an unlimited number of pairs so you can do `decode(columnA,'Dog','B', 'Cat', 'T', 'not a dog or cat')` without needing to nest decodes.

Comment: @StevieG I am not sure why you see the need to have the `decode` inside the `decode`.

Answer (score 0):

`DECODE` is universally used in the Oracle world, but I'd use the `CASE` statement, because it is much more readable:

```
SELECT CASE myinput
       WHEN 'Dog' THEN 'B'
       WHEN 'Cat' THEN 'T'
                  ELSE '?'
       END myoutput
  FROM ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select decode(columnA,'Dog', 'B','Cat', 'T', 'None') from dual;
```

Here is how the DECODE function works

```
DECODE([If ColumnA is] 'Dog' [then] 'B' [elsif] 'Cat' [then] 'T' ..... [else] 'None')
```

Comment: Well to the -1 voter - Please go through how to use a decode function - http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php